# Scrollbar partially showing Python

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

So I have a scrollbar, and it works decently but it does not completely appear, there is always a line or two that are left behind. Any idea why?

Here's the code:

```
lst=[('Nom','Total ','#Item')]
root=Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.configure(bg='#bdcabd')
root.title("Fichier de compabilité a 13%")

#I cut part of the code since it was not relevant to the matter at hand
    
Sfrm=LabelFrame(root, text="Data du Fichier")
Sfrm.place(height=255, width=500)

cnva=Canvas(Sfrm)
cnva.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='NS')

sb=Scrollbar(Sfrm,orient='vertical',command=cnva.yview)
sb.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky='NS')

rollfrm=Frame(cnva)
rollfrm.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='NS')

rollfrm.bind('<Configure>',lambda e:cnva.configure(scrollregion=cnva.bbox('all')))
cnva.create_window((0,0),window=rollfrm,anchor='nw')
cnva.configure(yscrollcommand=sb.set)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The scrollbar is the same height as the canvas, are you expecting it to be taller? Also, the scrollregion of the canvas is smaller than the canvas so there's nothing to scroll. It's not clear why you think it should look different than it does.

Comment: I know but once there is something to scroll the scrollbar is supposed to go from the top of the canvas to the bottom. Right? Well in my case there is a part at the bottom that does not show and I do not yet know why.

Comment: Please show an example that illustrates this.

Comment: Let it be! I solved it. Thank's for your comment it helped me clarify something!